# XSLT avoid new line added between element attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, newline, spaces

I have the following XML file as input and for each instance of the `<CI_DateTypeCode>` element I need to change `@codeListValue` attribute value.

The transformation works but I get on output **unnecessary/undesired new line** between the `@codeList` attribute and `@codeListValue` attribute.

As you can see, in the source XML file there's **no new line between attributes**.
How can I avoid this behavior?

**XML source file**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="c:\ISO19139_rve.xsl"?>
    <MD_Metadata xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd/gmd.xsd">
        <MD_DataIdentification>
            <citation>
                <CI_Citation>
                    <title>
                        <gco:CharacterString>Title</gco:CharacterString>
                    </title>
                    <date>
                        <CI_Date>
                            <date>
                                <gco:CharacterString>2014-04-15</gco:CharacterString>
                            </date>
                            <dateType>
                                <CI_DateTypeCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#CI_DateTypeCode" codeListValue="Creazione">Creazione</CI_DateTypeCode>
                            </dateType>
                        </CI_Date>
                    </date>
                </CI_Citation>
            </citation>
        </MD_DataIdentification>
    </MD_Metadata>
```

**XSL transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
    xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco"
    xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd"
    xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd"
    >

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- <CI_DateTypeCode>: @codeListValue attribute values -->
    <xsl:param name="pCIDateTypeCodeCreation" select="'creation'"/>
    <xsl:param name="pCIDateTypeCodePublication" select="'publication'"/>
    <xsl:param name="pCIDateTypeCodeRevision" select="'revision'"/>
    <xsl:param name="pCIDateTypeCodeOther" select="''"/>

    <!-- override: <CI_DateTypeCode> to apply @codeListValue attribute values -->
    <xsl:template match="gmd:CI_DateTypeCode/@codeListValue">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="lower-case(.) eq 'creazione'">
                <xsl:attribute name="codeListValue">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$pCIDateTypeCodeCreation"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="lower-case(.) eq 'pubblicazione'">
                <xsl:attribute name="codeListValue">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$pCIDateTypeCodePublication"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="lower-case(.) eq 'revisione'">
                <xsl:attribute name="codeListValue">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$pCIDateTypeCodeRevision"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="lower-case(.) eq 'rilievo'">
                <xsl:attribute name="codeListValue">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$pCIDateTypeCodeOther"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Actual XML output** (see new line with indentation between `@codeList` and `@codeListValue` attributes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="c:\ISO19139_rve.xsl"?>
<MD_Metadata xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco"
             xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
             xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd/gmd.xsd">
   <MD_DataIdentification>
      <citation>
         <CI_Citation>
            <title>
               <gco:CharacterString>Title</gco:CharacterString>
            </title>
            <date>
               <CI_Date>
                  <date>
                     <gco:CharacterString>2014-04-15</gco:CharacterString>
                  </date>
                  <dateType>
                     <CI_DateTypeCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#CI_DateTypeCode"
                                      codeListValue="creation">Creazione</CI_DateTypeCode>
                  </dateType>
               </CI_Date>
            </date>
         </CI_Citation>
      </citation>
   </MD_DataIdentification>
</MD_Metadata>
```

Comment: Why does it matter?  The presence or absence of whitespace between attributes in a single tag makes no difference to an XML parser.  Besides, I don't think there's any way to control this within XSLT - XSLT produces an output tree structure, but how to render that into XML is up to the serializer.

Comment: Change your `xsl:output` so it will not indent: `<xsl:output indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>`

Answer (score 2):

The output shown looks as if it comes from Saxon. Personally, I think it reads quite well. Of course, you don't have to have indentation at all (set `indent="no"` on `xsl:output`).

If you are indeed using Saxon, you can reduce the chance that attributes will wrap to a new line by increasing the maximum line length using `<xsl:output saxon:line-length="1000"/>`, say: though note that files with lines as long as this may screw up some text editors.

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters

Comment: @all If I set `indent="no"` I loose all the indentation and that's not what I want... I'm using Saxon with oXygen XML Editor but it's just for convenience during the creation of the transformation. Then I need to apply my final transformation to many files using a Windows Form Application and the .NET `XslCompiledTransform` classes, passing the xsl file.